# connecting to azure sql from Databricks workspace

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

Created azure Databricks and mounted storage object using service principal. Now I am trying to ingest data from Azure sql and the connections is resulting in failure.

```
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{serverName}.database.windows.net:1433;database={DatabaseName};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
table = "dbo.TableName"
user = 'username'
password = 'sqlAdminPasscode'
```

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("dbtable", tableName) \
    .load()
```

RESULTING IN:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host [REDACTED].database.windows.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: "[REDACTED].database.windows.net. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

note: I have allowed azure resources and services to assess the resource.

UPDATE:

```
CHANGED URL: 

url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://sql-NA.database.windows.net:1433;database=NA;user=NA@NA;password={sqlAdminPasscode};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;net;loginTimeout=30;"
```

ERROR CHANGE TO:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-1255730592229210>, line 7
      1 df = (spark.read
      2 .format("jdbc")
      3 .option("url", url)
      4 .option("dbtable", "TABLENAME")
      5 .option("user", adminname)
      6 .option("password", sqlAdminPasscode)
----> 7 .load()
      8 )

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:48, in _wrap_function.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46 start = time.perf_counter()
     47 try:
---> 48     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49     logger.log_success(
     50         module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature
     51     )
     52     return res
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://redacted.database.windows.net:1433;database=redacted;user=redacted@redacted;password={sqlAdminPasscode};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
```

finally

```
df = (spark.read
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", url)
.option("dbtable", "dbo.sometable")
.option("user", adminname)
.option("password", sqlAdminPasscode)
.load()
)
```

resolved the problem